# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que Iterator.next vuelva al principio del array?

Tags: java, array

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer para que Iterator.next vuleva a ponerse en la primera posición, como si recorriera un array circular.
El código que tengo implementado es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    protected List<Integer> participantes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        participantes.add(i);
    }
    Iterator iter = participantes.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        iter.next();
    }
    Object e = iter.next();
    int elemento = (int)e;
    System.out.println(elemento);
}
```

Lo que quiero es que elemento me devuelva el elemento en la primera posición del array, como si lo recorrieras circularmente pero no se como hacerlo con los métodos de la interfaz Iterator.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Has probado a volver a asignar el iterador? `iter = participantes.iterator;`

Comment: La interfaz Iterator no tiene forma de resetearse, podrías pedir un nuevo Iterator a la lista o usar otro sistema para recorrerla

Comment: Volví a asignar el iterador y ya me funciona como quiero, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De hecho lo puedes regresar a cualquier posición si solo lo que tu quieres al principio lo puedes hacer con [listIterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), o con [listIterator(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)  en donde index es el  indice específico, de tal forma que solo agregué la línea **iter = participantes.listIterator();** tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> participantes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        participantes.add(i);
    }
    Iterator iter = participantes.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        iter.next();
    }

    iter = participantes.listIterator();

    Object e = iter.next();
    int elemento = (int)e;
    System.out.println("Resultado = "+elemento);
}
```

Y el resultado fue el siguiente:

Resultado = 1